# Why is !!'0' == true when '0' == false

Tags: javascript

The question says it all as I understand !!false = false

Then if

```
0 == false // true 
'0' == false // true
```

why

```
!!0 == false 
!!'0' == true
```

Comment: `!` negates a boolean, so not not false is false....not false is true and not true is false

Comment: `'0'` is a non-empty string, so it's `true`

Comment: If you are trying to check just numbers and not strings you can use `!!+`

Comment: @Pointy then why console.log('0' == false) is true

Comment: The real question is why `'0' == false` evaluates to `true`, since `'0'` is a non-empty string. My guess is that `'0' == false` because the string is cast to an int, and `0` is falsey.

Comment: @heyza22 it is not `true`, that statement logs `false`.

Comment: @Pointy I meant '0' == false you said that '0' is true. where console.log('0' == false) gives true

Comment: here's my understanding which may not be correct. when you compare two values of different type with ==, javascript will convert both operands to the same type and then do strict comparision('==='), so '0' == false should be converted to 0 === 0, which is true.

Comment: `'0'` on its own evaluates to `true`. `'0' == false` is also `true` though because in order to compare them, the `==` causes both to be cast to the same type, in this case int. So `'0'` becomes `0`, and so does `false`. Still, this question is a duplicate and was already marked as such. The answers in the dupe explain this.

Comment: @ChrisG sure but why is not !!'0' cast in the same way? why !!'0' == false is false why it doesn't have the same logic as '0'

Comment: The `!!` is applied before the comparison. It comes down to order of operations. `2 + 3 == 5` becomes `5 == 5`, not `2 + false`.

Comment: Final comment: `!!'0' == false` is not `!!('0' == false)` but `(!!'0') == false`.

Answer (score 1):

string zero ('0') is a truthy value

`!!'0' == true`

```
!'0' -> !false -> true
```

So you're actually doing

`true == true`

Comment: I didn't downvote, but '0' == false in my console.log('0' == false) gives true. so its not seen as a not empty 
string

Comment: @heyza22 when you use `==` it tries to cerce both the values to the same type, so when it coerce `0` to boolean it is falsy, so you get `'0' == false` as true

Comment: but then why does the same logic not apply for !!'0' == false then it gives false

Comment: @heyza22 because `!` is having higher precedence than `==` so it is evaluated first and than `==` is evaluated

Comment: What is `ture`?

Comment: @connexo a typo !!!

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you stumbled across the importance of the `===` operator.

```
'0' == false;  // true
'0' === false; // false

Boolean('0');  // true

typeof('0');   // string
typeof(!'0');  // boolean

!'0' === false; // true
!!'0' === false // false
```

Answer (score 0):

The first negation converts string `'0'` to a boolean by calling of abstract function `ToBoolean`. According to `JavaScript` [specification](https://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/7.0/#sec-toboolean), only 7 values are evaluated/coerced/converted to false i.e are falsy:
`null`, `undefined`, `NaN`, Empty String, `+0`, `-0`, and `false`.

So, `'0'` is evaluted to a truthy, `!'0'` to `false` and `!!'0'` to true.

**PS**: Another cases of why `'0' == false` is evaluated to `true` is raised after the original question by the OP in a comment below. Even though not relevant to the original post, here is the explanation:

In the specification, section [Abstract Equality Comparison](https://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/7.0/#sec-abstract-equality-comparison) reads: "*When evaluating `x == y`, if the type of `y` is `Boolean`, first convert `y` to `Number` and then do the comparison again*".

So `Number(false)` is evaluated to `0`. In the next comparison run, string `'0'` is compared with number `0` i.e `'0' == 0`. The spec says convert the string to number and do the comparison again: `0 == 0`.

Comment: yes, but console.log('0' == false) is true

Comment: This, like pretty much all previous answers, fails to address why `'0' == false` evaluates to `true`... which is explained in the dupe, **as which this is already marked**.

Comment: @heyza22 Those are two different things. Truthy/Falsy only applies when it is used in a boolean context. When you use `!` it inverts the boolean so it is seen in a Boolean context (so `'0'` is truthy and negating it twice becomes `true`). That is not the case when you use `'0' == true`, because there the rules of Abstract Equality Comparison are used which converts both values to the same type before comparing. In that case `'0'` is converted to a number (`0`) instead of a boolean (`true`).

Comment: @heyza22 The case you mentioned in your comment is not relevant to the initial question. Anyways, I updated the answer. Hope it clears everything.